# how to connect to Cloud SQL from Google DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql, apache-beam

I'm trying to create a pipeline task using beam java SDK and Google Dataflow to move data from Cloud SQL to Elastic search

I've created the following class main method:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
    options.setProject("staging");      
    options.setTempLocation("gs://csv_to_sql_staging/temp"); 
    options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);        
    options.setGcpTempLocation("gs://csv_to_sql_staging/temp");
    options.setUsePublicIps(false);         
    options.setJobName("tamer-new");
    options.setSubnetwork("regions/us-central1/subnetworks/new-network");
    final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub");
    options.setGcpCredential(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new ElasticSearchIO().getClass().getResourceAsStream("/staging-b648da5d2b9b.json")).createScoped(SCOPES));            options.setServiceAccount("data-flow@staging.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
                    
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
                      
    p.begin();
                      
    PCollection < List < String >> rows = p.apply(JdbcIO. < List < String >> read().withQuery("select u.id, u.name from user_table").withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://google/nameDB_new?cloudSqlInstance=staging:europe-west1:sql-staging-instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&user=user&password=password&useSSL=false")).withRowMapper(new RowMapper < List < String >> () {

        @Override public List < String > mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
            List < String > addRow = new ArrayList < String > ();


            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                addRow.add(i - 1, String.valueOf(resultSet.getObject(i)));
            }

            //LOG.info(String.join(",", addRow));

            return addRow;

        }
    })

    .withCoder(ListCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder. < Object > of ()))

    );

    Write w = ElasticsearchIO.write().withConnectionConfiguration(
        ElasticsearchIO.ConnectionConfiguration.create(new String[] {
            "https://host:9243"
        }, "user-temp", "String").withUsername("elastic").withPassword("password")
    );

    rows.apply(w.compose(new SerializableFunction() {

       @Override public Object apply(Object input) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return input;
        }
    }));


    p.run().waitUntilFinish();

}
```

and below is the pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.harmonica.dataflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>com-harmonica-dataflow</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.6.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <beam.version>2.19.0</beam.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ossrh.snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype OSS Repository Hosting</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
<!--  Beam Lib -->
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>        
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>${beam.version}</version>  
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
      
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>           
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.15</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and when I execute this command:

```
man exec mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.dataflow.ElasticSearchIO
```

The worker started successfully but then cant connect to the the Cloud SQL:
even thought I've done the flowing:

- I've created a service account with owner access to the project and passed it to the runner options
- I've created a VPC network with a name of new-network with a range of IP of 190.10.0.0/16 and assigned it to the pipeline options and then whitlisted this range in the cloud SQL

and however Im still getting this error:

> Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException:
> Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:194)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:165)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:63)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:50)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks.replaceDirectedNetworkNodes(Networks.java:87)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.create(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:125)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:352)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:305)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:140)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:120)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:107)
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException:
> Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:34)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeSetup(Unknown
> Source)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.deserializeCopy(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:80)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.peek(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:62)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.UserParDoFnFactory.create(UserParDoFnFactory.java:95)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DefaultParDoFnFactory.create(DefaultParDoFnFactory.java:75)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.createParDoOperation(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:264)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.access$000(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:86)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:183)
> ... 14 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
> PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure The last packet
> sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has
> not received any packets from the server.)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:735)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:605)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:809)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.setup(JdbcIO.java:881)
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException:
> Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
> server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
> from the server.
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:53)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:355)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:116)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:731)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:605)
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:809)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.setup(JdbcIO.java:881)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeSetup(Unknown
> Source)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.deserializeCopy(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:80)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.peek(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:62)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.UserParDoFnFactory.create(UserParDoFnFactory.java:95)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DefaultParDoFnFactory.create(DefaultParDoFnFactory.java:75)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.createParDoOperation(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:264)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.access$000(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:86)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:183)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:165)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:63)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:50)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks.replaceDirectedNetworkNodes(Networks.java:87)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.create(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:125)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:352)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:305)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:140)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:120)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:107)
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link
> failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0
> milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the
> server. sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
> com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
> ... 32 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
> (Connection timed out) java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
> Method)
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
> java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
> sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
> com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.createSslSocket(CoreSocketFactory.java:233)
> com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect(CoreSocketFactory.java:185)
> com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:48)
> com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:38)
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
> ... 35 more

Plz any help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried any of the workarounds provided on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699643/connecting-to-cloud-sql-from-dataflow-job)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below piece of code to establish the connection:

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

```
    //Increase pool size based on your records

    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(
            "jdbc:mysql://google/test?cloudSqlInstance=dataflowtest-:us-central1:sql-test&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
    dataSource.setUser("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(6);

    JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration config = JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(dataSource);

    // ADD rewriteBatchedStatements=true to improve write speed"

    PCollection<KV<String, String>> sqlResult = p.apply(JdbcIO.<KV<String, String>>read()
            .withDataSourceConfiguration(config)
            .withQuery("select * from test_table").withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))
            .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<String, String>>() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public KV<String, String> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                    return KV.of(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2));
                }
            }));
```

Add below dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This should work..

Answer (score 0):

If possible try the below code for sql connection:

```
    connection = connectToCloudSql(map.get(LiteralConstant.URL.toString()),
            map.get(LiteralConstant.USERNAME.toString()), map.get(LiteralConstant.PASSWORD.toString()));
```

Then use the below piece of code to get result from sql connection:

```
statement = connection.prepareCall("query"); 
statement.execute();
resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();

int count = rsmd.getColumnCount();
if(!resultSet.next() || count < 1)
    throw new ConnectionFailureException("Failed to connect to Cloud SQL");

for (int k = 1; k <= count; k++) {
    row.set(rsmd.getColumnName(k), resultSet.getString(k));
}
```

Get the above result in PCollection
Note: ***Don't forget to enable Cloud sql api and Cloud sql admin api.***

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId> <!-- mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6 if using 6.x.x -->
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This above piece of code worked in my case. Let me know in case this solution works for you.

Comment: Instead of creating template, run your code in direct runner and check whether sql connection is happening or not? Have you enabled all the cloud sql api in your project?

Comment: yes its working at direct runner, and yes all Cloud Sql APIs are enabled

Comment: Did you able to fetch any row from Cloud SQL through DirectRunner? Just check the connection object val. I was talking about CLOUD SQL ADMIN API. The same issue I faced some months back, it's because of this API, Otherwise I don't see anything wrong in your code, but I usually go with getConnection for this type of use-cases.

Comment: so any way to trace this? when I put wrong name in the cloud instance I got an error of the instance not found, so it seems that it can find the DB instance, when I see the Cloud sql logs I see nothing

Comment: I believe you have have few tables in CloudSQL, get count(*) from any of the table and log that value in ParDO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207771/discussion-between-miles212-and-tamer-saleh).

Comment: Hey miles212@ - Can you update your snippet to use more recent versions of mysql-connector-java and mysql-socket-factory? the 5.x package is very outdated

Comment: @kurtisvg I’m using the latest and still having the issue

Comment: @kurtisvg its working fine using DirectRunner but still same issue with the DataFlow runner, there is a problem connecting to the Cloud SQL